# OpenGL ES 2 (iOS) Morph / Animate between two set of vertexes

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I have two sets of vertexes used as a line strip:

1. Vertexes1
2. Vertexes2

It's important to know that these vertexes have previously unknown values, as they are dynamic.

I want to make an animated transition (morph) between these two. I have come up with two different ways of doing this:

### **Option 1:**

Set a Time uniform in the vertex shader, that goes from **0 - 1**, where I can do something like this:

```
// Inside main() in the vertex shader
float originX = Position.x;
float destinationX = DestinationVertexPosition.x;
float interpolatedX = originX + (destinationX - originX) * Time;

gl_Position.x = interpolatedX;
```

As you probably see, this has one problem: How do I get the **"DestinationVertexPosition"** in there?

### **Option 2:**

Make the interpolation calculation outside the vertex shader, where I loop through each vertex and create a third vertex set for the interpolated values, and use that to render:

```
// Pre render
// Use this vertex set to render
InterpolatedVertexes

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
   float originX = Vertexes1[i].x;
   float destinationX = Vertexes2[i].x;
   float interpolatedX = originX + (destinationX - originX) * Time;

   InterpolatedVertexes[i].x = interpolatedX;
}
```

I have highly simplified these two code snippets, just to make the idea clear.

Now, from the two options, I feel like the first one is definitely better in terms of performance, given stuff happens at the shader level, AND I don't have to create a new set of vertexes each time the **"Time"** is updated.

So, now that the introduction to the problem has been covered, I would appreciate any of the following three things:

1. A discussion of better ways of achieving the desired results in OpenGL ES 2 (iOS).
2. A discussion about how **Option 1** could be implemented properly, either by providing the **"DestinationVertexPosition"** or by modifying the idea somehow, to better achieve the same result.
3. A discussion about how **Option 2** could be implemented.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ES 2 you specify such attributes as you like — there's therefore no problem with specifying attributes for both `origin` and `destination`, and doing the linear interpolation between them in the vertex shader. However you really shouldn't do it component by component as your code suggests you want to as GPUs are vector processors, and the `mix` GLSL function will do the linear blend you want. So e.g. (with obvious inefficiencies and assumptions)

```
int sourceAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "sourceVertex");
glVertexAttribPointer(sourceAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, sourceLocations);

int destAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "destVertex");
glVertexAttribPointer(destAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, destLocations);
```

And:

```
gl_Position = vec4(mix(sourceVertex, destVertex, Time), 1.0);
```

Comment: Thanks Tommy! I ended up making the modifications you mentioned, adding a destination vertex to the shader.

Answer (score 3):

Your two options here have a trade off: supply twice the geometry once and interpolate between that, or supply only one set of geometry, but do so for each frame. You have to weigh geometry size vs. upload bandwidth.

Given my experience with iOS devices, I'd highly recommend option 1. Uploading new geometry on every frame can be extremely expensive on these devices.

If the vertices are constant, you can upload them once into one or two vertex buffer objects (VBOs) with the `GL_STATIC_DRAW` flag set. The PowerVR SGX series has hardware optimizations for dealing with static VBOs, so they are very fast to work with after the initial upload.

As far as how to upload two sets of vertices for use in a single shader, geometry is just another input attribute for your shader. You could have one, two, or more sets of vertices fed into a single vertex shader.  You just define the attributes using code like

```
attribute vec3 startingPosition;
attribute vec3 endingPosition;
```

and interpolate between them using code like

```
vec3 finalPosition = startingPosition * (1.0 - fractionalProgress) + endingPosition * fractionalProgress;
```

**Edit:** Tommy points out the `mix()` operation, which I'd forgotten about and is a better way to do the above vertex interpolation.

In order to inform your shader program as to where to get the second set of vertices, you'd use pretty much the same `glVertexAttribPointer()` call for the second set of geometry as the first, only pointing to that VBO and attribute.

Note that you can perform this calculation as a vector, rather than breaking out all three components individually. This doesn't get you much with a `highp` default precision on current PowerVR SGX chips, but could be faster on future ones than doing this one component at a time.

You might also want to look into other techniques used for vertex skinning, because there might be other ways of animating vertices that don't require two full sets of vertices to be uploaded.

The one case that I've heard where option 2 (uploading new geometry on each frame) might be preferable is in specific cases where using the Accelerate framework to do vector manipulation of the geometry ends up being faster than doing the skinning on-GPU. I remember the Unity folks were talking about this once, but I can't remember if it was for really small or really large sets of geometry. Option 1 has been faster in all the cases I've worked with myself.

Comment: Thanks Brad for your thorough explanation! I ended up doing as you and Tommy mentioned, adding another set of vertex to the shader. The results are very good.